# Add first item of list to front of other list Python

Tags: list, for-loop, matrix, insert

Hello I want to insert all items of a list to the front of the lists in a matrix. As so:
How can I fix this? Thanks!

The weight_matrix being:

```
[['tekst4.txt', 'tekst3.txt', 'tekst2.txt', 'tekst1.txt'], 
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.41503749927884376, 0.8300749985576875, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]]
```

The list that needs to be inserted at the front of the lists:

```
['', 'noot', 'wim', 'aap', 'mies']
```

The output should look like this:

```
[[' ','tekst4.txt', 'tekst3.txt', 'tekst2.txt', 'tekst1.txt'], 
['noot', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
['wim', 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['aap', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['mies', 0.41503749927884376, 0.8300749985576875, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]]
```

I am trying this:

```
weight_matrix = [[b.insert(0,i) for i in a] for a, b in zip(weight_matrix, terms)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with list comprehension:

```
wm = [['tekst4.txt', 'tekst3.txt', 'tekst2.txt', 'tekst1.txt'], 
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.41503749927884376, 0.8300749985576875, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]]

ad = ['', 'noot', 'wim', 'aap', 'mies']

wm_new = [[ad[i]] + wm[i] for i in range(len(ad))]
```

Result:

```
[['', 'tekst4.txt', 'tekst3.txt', 'tekst2.txt', 'tekst1.txt'], 
['noot', 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], ['wim', 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['aap', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
['mies', 0.41503749927884376, 0.8300749985576875, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]]
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me allot, was stuck on this for hours

Comment: Glad to help :)